# нарисовать елку Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, консоль

```
const a = new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => i)
```

имеется массив с сотней значений.
нужно перевести цифры в символ * и сделать так чтобы в консоли рисовалась елка с углами

```
let i = 0, j = 0;
let max = 10;
let space = "",
    star = "";

while (i < max) {
    space = "";
    star = "";
    for (j = 0; j < max - i; j++) space += " ";
    for (j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++) star += "*";
    console.log(space + star);
    i++;
};
```

нужно использовать  массив
перевести его значения в символ *
и построить елку

Comment: Приложите вашу попытку

Comment: приложил свою попытку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сойдёт за ёлку? =)

```js
const a = new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);
a.forEach(num => {
  const [a, b] = [num/10|0, num%10];
  console.log('*'.repeat(a) + '*'.repeat(b));
});
```

Или вот так:

```js
const a = new Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);
a.forEach(num => {
  const [a, b] = [num / 10 | 0, num % 10];
  console.log(
      ' '.repeat(9 - (a + b) / 2) 
    + '*'.repeat(a) 
    + '*'.repeat(b));
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое